# how to change date datatype from object to int64 without changing it's values

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a column in my dataframe which consists of date 1/6/2023 (m/d/yyy) format. The date datatype is object but I want to convert it from object to int64 data type. I have tried the following code but it is drastically changing date values:

```
df = df.astype({'date':'int'})
```

is changing my values drastically is there any other alternative for the same ?

```
df = df.astype({'date':'int'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to datetimes, then to strings - e.g. here `YYYYMMDD` format and last to integers:

```
print (df)
       date
0  1/6/2023

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y%m%d').astype(int)
print (df)
       date
0  20230601
```